# How do I install old versions of Ruby Gems?

Tags: rubygems

I need to install an old version of [cluster_chef](https://rubygems.org/gems/cluster_chef/versions/3.0.4), but it has been yanked. My project has insane dependencies, so I'm not sure how to install something that has been yanked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not possible to install yanked gems. But you could perhaps work around your issue by relaxing at bit your version dependencies in your project Gemfile?

Instead of:

```
gem 'cluster_chef', '3.0.4'
```

Use:

```
gem 'cluster_chef', '~> 3.0.4'
```

If the version 3.0.4 of `cluster_chef` is not available, Bundler will install the latest version of the gem that satisfies all dependencies.

If you’re still stuck in your dependencies, your last solution is to fork and edit the libraries depending on the yanked version of cluster_chef to use a newer version of it.

Comment: If I get the code for an older version `https://github.com/infochimps/cluster_chef/tree/v3.0.6`, how do I install it?

Comment: You can build a gem from the `cluster_chef` folder: `gem build cluster_chef.gemspec` and then `gem install cluster_chef-3.0.6.gem`

Anyway, this version of the gem isn’t yanked, so you can as well do: `gem install cluster_chef -v=3.0.6`

Comment: You can’t. There’s no tag `3.0.4` so you can’t checkout the source for that version, and version `3.0.4` was yanked on rubygems.org. I strongly suggest your upgrade to an installable version. Gems are often yanked for a good reason.